# How to merge 2 data frames with different keys

Tags: python, merge, key, mapping

Can you please help on my case as below. I want to merge 2 dataset to get the expected results as below:

Df 1: A data frame summarises value of features of each ID as below:

| id | feature 1 | feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | 3.4 |
| 2 | 2.3 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 3.5 | 6 |

Df 2: Mapping tables to determine corresponding segment for each feature based on min/max thresholds of each features
|Feature|Min |Max|segment|
|--| --- | --- |---|
|Feature 1 | 0 |1|1|
|Feature 1 |1|2|2|
|Feature 1 |2 |inf|3|
|Feature 2 | 0 |4|1|
|Feature 2 |4|5|2|
|Feature |5 |inf|3|

Expected results: I want to merge df1 with mapping table in df2 to get corresponding segment

| id | feature 1 | feature 2 | feature 1 segment | feature 2 segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | 3.4 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2.3 | 1.2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3.5 | 6 | 3 | 3 |

Thanks a lot for helps

Comment: what you have shown is df1 and df2?

Comment: Could you see the tables in df1 and df 2? Let me upload picture as below. I think there are problems when showing. Thanks a lot

Comment: Posted your solution. If the answer helped you, mark it by checking the box below the upper and lower triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'feature 1': [1.2, 2.3, 3.5], 'feature 2': [3.4, 1.2, 6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': ['feature 1', 'feature 1', 'feature 1', 'feature 2', 'feature 2', 'feature 2'],
                    'Min': [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5], 'Max': [1, 2, np.inf, 4, 5, np.inf], 'segment': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})


df1 = df1.set_index('id')

def func_data(x, q):
    df = df2[df2['Feature'] == q]
    ttt = np.where((x.values[0] >= df['Min']) & (x.values[0] <= df['Max']))
    index = df1.index[ttt][0]

    return index


df1['feature_1_segment'] = df1.groupby(['id'])['feature 1'].apply(func_data, 'feature 1')
df1['feature_2_segment'] = df1.groupby(['id'])['feature 2'].apply(func_data, 'feature 2')
df1 = df1.reset_index()

print(df1)
```

Output

```
   id  feature 1  feature 2  feature_1_segment  feature_2_segment
0   1        1.2        3.4                  2                  1
1   2        2.3        1.2                  3                  1
2   3        3.5        6.0                  3                  3
```

Here, first the 'id' column is set as an index. A 'func_data ' function is created to determine which range each number falls into. The np.where function from numpy is used to test for a range. Get indexes by 'id'.